# Submit embedded form without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have an embedded form on the admin page which when submitted does not perform any error checking or input data into the database, and reloads the admin page.

This happens with both add_data.php and add_user.php when loaded through the admin page, but do work on their own page.

How can the form be submitted without reloading the page?

Admin page:

```
<?php 
require('../phpinclude/init.php');
include_once('../template/head.php');
?>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".load_content").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#content").load($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
</script>           

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a class="load_content" href="../data/index.php">Data</a></li>
        <li><a class="load_content" href="../template/add_data.php">Add Data</a></li>
        <li><a class="load_content" href="../template/add_user.php">Add User</a></li>
        <li><a class="load_content" href="../template/list_users.php">List User</a></li>
        <li><a href="../template/logout.php">Logout</a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>



<div id="content">
    <!-- Content gets loaded here -->
    <h2>Welcome!</h2>
</div>
```

Add Data Page:

```
<?php
require('../phpinclude/init.php');

$name = $link = $name_msg = $link_msg = $submit_msg ='';
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
    include_once("../phpinclude/db_connect.php");

    if (empty($_POST["new_name"])) {
        $name_msg = "Name is required";
    } else if (preg_match("#[^a-z._\-0-9]#i",$_POST["new_name"])) {
        $name_msg = "Only letters, numbers . _ - allowed";
    } else {
        $name = sanitise($_POST["new_name"]);
        $checkName = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM db_data WHERE name='$name' LIMIT 1");
        $checkName->execute(array($name));
        if ($checkName->rowcount()) {
            $name_msg = 'This name is already in use';
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["new_link"])) {
        $link_msg = "Link is required";
    } else {
        $link = sanitise($_POST["new_link"]);   
        $checkLink = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM db_data WHERE link='$link' LIMIT 1");
        $checkLink->execute(array($link));
        if ($checkLink->rowcount()) {
            $link_msg = 'This link address is already in use';
        }   
    }


    if($name == "" || $link == "") {
        echo 'The form is missing information';
    } else if ($checkName->rowcount()) {
        echo 'That name is already in use';
    } else if ($checkLink->rowcount()) {
        echo 'that link is already in use';
    }  else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO db_data (name, link)
        VALUES (:name, :link)";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':link', $link, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        echo 'form SUBMITTED';
        exit();
    }
}
?>          

<h1>Add new Data</h1>
<div>
    <form action="" method="POST" role="form">
        <!-- NAME -->
        <label for="new_name">DATA Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="new_name" name="new_name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
        <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $name_msg;?></span>
        <br>
        <!-- LINK -->
        <label for="new_link">Link</label>
        <input type="text" id="new_link" name="new_link" value="<?php echo $link;?>">
        <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $link_msg;?></span>
        <br>
        <!-- SUBMIT -->
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        <span style="color:red;"><?php echo $submit_msg;?></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

add_user.php is very similar to add_data.php, only with more parameters to be submitted.

Comment: It's the `<form>` (specifically the `submit` function) you want to link to javascript and `e.preventDefault()`, not the `<a>` links. Keep searching SO you should find an existing answer. I usually have an `<a>` link `.click()` the form's submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
 //prevent the html form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url : $(this).att('action');
    data : $(this).serialize(),
    //set the response as the submit message
    success: function (response) {
    $('#submit-msg').html(response);
    }
});
});
```

Add an action to the form, in this case the php file itself:
`<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" role="form">`

Also change your html like so:
`<span id="submit-msg" style="color:red;"></span>`

Comment: I can't seem to get the javascript to work. I've added it to admin.php and add_data.php. 
Adding <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> to the form action gets the form to submit but redirects the page to ..../template/add_data.php

Comment: The form action needs to have the proper link.